# C++ spaceship operator multilevel compare?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

Does the new C++20 spaceship operator allow a *concise* way of expressing short-circuited multiple-criteria comparison? Something better than this:

```
const firstCriteriaComparisonResult = lhs.x <=> rhs.x;
return firstCriteriaComparisonResult != 0 ? firstCriteriaComparisonResult : lhs.y <=> rhs.y;
```

Comment: I was under the impression it automatically did a member-wise compare; [cppreference says yes.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons)

Comment: That said, if you only want to compare one or two elements instead of *all* of them, just do the normal comparison overloads.

Comment: Re comment 1: If `operator<=>()` member must be a template function (templated on RHS type) then it must be written by hand. Template opeators cannot be `= default`ed.

Re comment 2: there are no "normal comparison overloads" and there never were. Comparison overloading has always been a mess, and the three-way compare operator was added to the language precisely to address this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual `tie`-and-compare approach works with spaceship too:

```
return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y) <=> std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y);
```

Comment: I honestly didn't know that one! I'm back to C++ after a decade, and `std::tie()` is apparently about that old.